# "Entity Content" not available in views UI

Tags: views, entities

I have installed [Eva](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module (7.x-1.2). I can't see Entity Views attachemet section on my views screen.

I want a replicate what is described in this video for creating galleries. Its 2:30 mins in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPlY8MUl0XQ

Please help.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Now it looks like you are reporting Eva bug. If that so, you are in wrong place. If not, please explain in *your* words what are you trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I see that there is no solution for this. It works with older version of views and I cannot change now. Is there any other option to link uploaded images to gallery, without using EVA module? or Should I raise another question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the alternate solution to the problem. If the Entity content is not showing up, add EVA view display, show do (admin/structure/views/add new views/add/EVA filed)